# How to determine if a number is a prime in a faster fashion using additional threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, primes

I have a program which is PrimeNumbers class. It displays if the x is a prime or not. The x is the number being analyzed in the program.

There is a time on how long will the program take to know the answer. x is so big it takes 9 seconds to know the answer. How could the program run faster using more threads? I am having a hard time on getting how to   implement thread in this situation.

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    private static int x = 2147483647;

    public static boolean prime= true;

    public static void main(String[]args){

        long start,  end, elapsetime;
        start= System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int y=2; y<x; y++){
            if(x % y == 0){
                prime=false;
                System.out.println(y);
                break;
            }
        }

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        elapsetime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Prime: " + prime);

        System.out.println(elapsetime+ " mill sec " + (elapsetime / 1000 
            + " seconds."));

    }       
}
```

Comment: There are many improvements you can make to make this run (much) faster, but they don't include multithreading.

Comment: You might want to get a better algorithm.

Comment: @Kon Why? Multithreading can help also.

Comment: @talex Efficiently multithreading a (deterministic) primality test is pretty complicated, while there are many incredibly simple algorithms to improve upon this one here (seriously a single statement would improve the asymptotic complexity here)

Comment: What algoritm should be use?

Comment: Yeah, don't waste your time trying to do this with multiple threads. The answer below by Munyari will do it in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to ignore whether you've got the most efficient approach and focus on how your current code could be faster with more threads.

You currently iterate through all the numbers from `2 -> x` and perform a simple test. A way to improve performance might be to split this task into *Z* chunks and start *Z* threads to perform the tests in parallel.

E.g. if you had two threads, you would have one thread examine `2 -> x/2` and the other examine `x/2 + 1 -> x`. Each thread should break from its testing if a global (and probably `volatile`) flag is set to true, which would indicate the other thread has disproved the prime.

Comment: Just another suggestion when the flag is changed to true you can kill all other threads and just say not a prime number. you don't need to wait till the entire processing is done !

Comment: @StackFlowed That was what I meant by "*Each thread should break from its testing if a global... flag is set to true*".

Comment: @user3802633 Why don't you try and do it yourself based on my description? There are a lot of resources out there explaining how to do multi-threading. Post another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your *primality test* is very inefficient, you're looping over each number less than x. 
How can you improve it? This [link should be helpful.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

A good algorithm would be the AKS test, or Sieve of Eratosthenes. The code below implements one of the algorithms from the wiki article, which is much more efficient than the test you posted.

```
public static boolean isPrime(long n) { 

    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality test

    if (n <= 3) return n > 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 5; i*i <=n; i+=6) {
      if (n % i == 0 || n % (i+2) == 0) return false; 
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is _NOT_ the AKS primality test.

Comment: The test shown is decent and simple trial division, fine for small numbers, and probably good for the original question.  Re the other suggestions, AKS is a terrible method in practice (it's *really* slow), and SoE is used for generating primes, not determining primality of a single input.  If you want better performance than the trial division for larger inputs, I'd recommend BPSW or M-R tests (both can be deterministic for 64-bit numbers).

Answer (score 1):

If you intersted for a better algorithm Munyari has already suggested one.

Ignoring this following example can help you how you can make parallely execute an algorithm (even if it is a stupid algorithm)

We need a class which implements Callable interface (similar one to Runnable). It should get the part of the job and calculate it.

```
public class PrimeChecker implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private final long numberToCheck;
    private final long start;
    private final long end;

    public PrimeChecker(long numberToCheck, long start, long end) {
        this.numberToCheck = numberToCheck;
        this.start = start;
        if (end >= numberToCheck) {
            this.end = numberToCheck - 1;
        }else{
            this.end = end;
        }
        System.out.println("A PrimeChecker with start " + start + " and end " + end + " values to check number "
                + numberToCheck);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        boolean prime = true;
        long current = start;

        if (current != 2 && (current % 2 == 0)) {
            current = current + 1;
        }

        for (; current < end; current = current + 2) {
            if (numberToCheck % current == 0) {
                prime = false;
                System.out.println("The number " + numberToCheck + " is divisable with " + current);
                return prime;
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }

}
```

It simply `start` from a number and check if the given number `numberToCheck` is divisable and continues until it reaches the number `end`.

In the Main class we have to create multiple PrimeChecker jobs and execute them parallely. For this purpose we use Java's ExecutorService. It creates for us a thread pool. And then we can divide the job on multiple PrimeCheckers. Finally we execute them `invokeAll` method of `ExecutorService`. This gives us a Future list, which contains results of each jobs that we executed parallely.

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean prime= true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        long numberToCheck = 5333334345L;
        int numberOfThreads = 10;
        System.out.println("Checking if the number " + numberToCheck + " ...");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        List<PrimeChecker> primeCheckers = new ArrayList<PrimeChecker>();

        long partOfNumber = (long) Math.ceil((double)numberToCheck/ numberOfThreads);
        long start = 2 ;
        long end = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
            end = end + partOfNumber;
            primeCheckers.add(new PrimeChecker(numberToCheck, start, end));
            start = end+1;
        }

        List<Future<Boolean>> futures = executor.invokeAll(primeCheckers);

        for(Future<Boolean> future : futures){
            prime = future.get();
            if(prime == false){
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number " + numberToCheck + " is " + (prime ? "a prime" :"NOT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! a prime") + " number");

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsetime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(elapsetime + " milliseconds");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You can try it with different numbers of threads (see `numberOfThreads` variable) to see the difference.

I hope it is a useful example for you, to understand multi threading better. (Be careful: It is only a tiny tiny part part of the whole threading theme)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But I really need to use thread. Is it impossible? :(

Comment: What do you mean with really threads? The solution uses multi threading really.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to implement the prime check yourself, I would propose to use the API. You can control the certainty, depending on your needs. In the example it is: 1-(1/2)<sup>100</sup>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger mersenne = new BigInteger("2").pow(521).add(BigInteger.ONE.negate());
    System.out.println("digits of the number: " + mersenne.toString().length());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final int certainty = 100;
    boolean isPrime = mersenne.isProbablePrime(certainty);
    System.out.println("elapsed millis: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    System.out.println("isPrime       : " + isPrime);
}
```

**edit**
Here is an optimised version of the proposed example.

```
public class PrimeNumbers {
    private static int x = 2147483647;
    public static boolean prime= true;

    public static void main(String[]args){

        long start, end, elapsetime;
        int divisor = 1;

        start= System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            prime = false;
            divisor = 2;
        } else {
            // - you can use an increment of two
            // because you don't need to check
            // for a divisor which is a multiple
            // of two
            // - you don't need to check for any divisor
            // which is greater than x/2
            for(int y=3; y < x/2; y += 2){
                if(x % y == 0){
                    prime=false;
                    divisor = y;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Prime: " + prime);
        if (!prime) {
            System.out.println("divisible by: " + divisor);
        }

        elapsetime = end - start;
        System.out.println(elapsetime+ " mill sec " + (elapsetime / 1000
            + " seconds."));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't I use flag or turn to make the process fast?

Comment: Hi @user3802633, if the limitation "should work for primes which can be stored into an int variable" fit your needs, you can optimise the code for example like shown in my second code example. Other optimisations are still possible.